# How can I get path java source code in runtime?

Tags: java, servlets, path

Is there no way to get path of Java source code in runtime?

Python can get it's path in runtime by using below code

```py
import os
file_path = (os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) )
```

Many people saids I can get path by using `System.getProperty("user.dir")` or `new File(".").getAbsolutePath()`.
But both method returns the path where java source code is executed...

For example, if source code is in `/User/Desktop/Project/src/test.java` and execute it at `/User/Desktop`, it returns `/User/Desktop` instead of `/User/Desktop/Project/src/test.java`.

Is there no way to get path of source file?
⋇This java file works as servlet to handle AJAX request

---

#### Addition - Purpose of finding source code path

I wrote python script and executing it by using `Runtime().getRuntime().exec()`.
I want to find python script without absolute path (I don't like path hardcoding).
So I'm trying to find java source code path and compute python source code path based on java path.

Comment: The location of the source code doesn't feature when you're running your program. Please ask about how to achieve what you're really trying to do. Are you trying to read your java files for some reason? Are you trying to read configuration/properties files?

Comment: @ernest_k Updated My question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this in java, because (unlike Python) java is compiled language and source code usually not bundled in application.

Comment: As I mentioned in question, This java source code is servlet which handle POST AJAX request. I can get servlet context by using `ServletContext context = getServletContext();`
Then, does `context.getRealPath` change properly when computer is changed?

Comment: @Damotorie yes. but it doesn't point to source code (which is not deployed with app).

Answer (score -2):

Maybe we can use the script "echo $PATH", it will print the whole Path that include the "JAVA_HOME" if you are run on Linux. The batch script for Windows is "where java", it will return the java's path. 
Hopes it can help you.

Comment: @talex I guess, my question made confusion because JAVA use JAVA_PATH environment variable

Comment: @Damotorie java doesn't use `JAVA_PATH` environment variable.

Comment: @talex Yes, your right, I confused, Java is still unfamiliar to me